# iTextSharp long time loading on first time

Tags: .net, itext

I'm using iTextSharp to create pdf documents on a fly but my problem is because the first time it takes too much time to complete the pdf generation. The next times it goes faster. Someone knows if there is a way to solve this situation.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ngen.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to eliminate JIT compilation and type-safety verification (usual startup activities).